# Complete $\mu$-recursive function that is not primitive recursive

Tags: computability, recursion, primitive-recursion

Could you find an example of a complete $\mu$-recursive function that is not a primitive function?

Answer (score 5):

There are two standard approaches: diagonalization and rate of growth.

The definition of primitive recursive functions (whichever one you use) allows enumerating them $f_1,f_2,\ldots$. Since each primitive recursive function is total, the function $f(n) = f_n(n)+1$ is recursive. It is clearly *not* primitive recursive.

The other approach is exemplified by the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), which is clearly recursive but grows too fast to be primitive recursive.